# How to fix `require': cannot load such file -- nokogiri/2.1/nokogiri (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I see many answers for this error when ruby version is =>2.2, but in my computer installed ruby version is [ruby 2.1.8p440]
I get this error when starting a server ( rails server ).

Gemfile

```
    source 'http://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.8'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
#gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'pg', '0.18.2'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
#gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'

gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production


# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.3.4'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'

gem 'ckeditor', '4.1.6'
gem 'carrierwave', '0.10.0'
gem 'fog', '~> 1.3.1'
gem 'mini_magick', '4.5.1'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.1.0'
gem 'nokogiri', '>= 1.5.0'


# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin]
```

[image: Error when starting server]

Comment: Please share your `Gemfile` and the file against which shows error.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I have an error. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `bundle` (or `bundle install`, but `bundle` does the same thing), to install the gems that are necessary for the app to run.

Comment: Thanks Keith, I tried. but it not works. I get same error.

Comment: Is nokogiri specified in your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock files?  Maybe try manually `gem install nokogiri` and see if that helps.

Comment: I add nokogiri to my gemfile and already install globally, but, it not works.

Comment: Maybe try running `gem env` and make sure the nokogiri gem is in one of the directory trees specified in the "GEM PATHS" section.

Comment: I check, they are in the same folder. I am going just remove nokogiri and find other solution. Thanks.